# What is the difference between ?android:colorControlHighlight and ?colorControlHighlight

Tags: android, android-layout

I see both `?android:colorControlHighlight` and `?colorControlHighlight` in our code base, and they seem to behave the same.

According to [References to theme attributes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes) doc, the `android` part is optional. Are these indeed the same? If not, which one should be used where?

Answer (score 1):

Attributes starting from `android:` are system resources.

Attribute `colorControlHighlight` belongs to `Material` theme and is available in system resources starting from API 21.

So `?android:colorControlHighlight` will not work in older versions.

`?colorControlHighlight` - uses value specified in project resources. More precisely - in `AppCompatTheme`. We can use it without additional prefix because `AppCompat` lib is linked to your project and all its attributes are included to the project.